# Lenovo laptops System update create admin accounts automatically

Tags: windows, security

Lenovo's system update program can be started without administrator right. When the service starts, it creates a temporary administrator account to perform the installation.

Why can a windows application have right to create an administrator-level account? How can I achieve it when I want to create a similar program?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to TVSU. A design point of TVSU is that even limited users can install updates from Lenovo. And to accomplish this, the TVSU service creates a temporary admin account with a randomized username and password, then uses it to do the installations on behalf of the limited user. This is the only time the account is created. The account is not created when an admin user does updates, because the admin user already has the permissions needed to do installations.

The account is supposed to be deleted after the TVSU session finishes, but I'm aware of a case where this doesn't happen and the account stays around. However there isn't any security risk to this because both the account and password are random and not known by anything except the specific TVSU process that created them, and this process ended the last time TVSU was closed. You can safely ignore the account, delete the account, or else it should be deleted the next time TVSU is run.